# Should I frame energy walls inside sill plates that extend inside the foundation?

Tags: basement, framing

So...I'm getting ready to finish our basement, and I noticed that the pressure treated sill plate (I assume that's what it's called) overhangs the foundation by about 2-2.5". Should I just put my framing so that it butts up to that? I guess I would lose a slight bit of space, but it shouldn't be a huge deal, I suppose.

What are your thoughts for a DIYer who's new to framing?

Comment: A photo would help greatly. I'm not sure if we're dealing with half-height or full-height walls or what, and what other factors are at play (windows, etc.). Chances are you can cut the plates back, but I'm not sure at this point.

Comment: Why would treated sills overhang the concrete foundation? I thought treated sills would be 2x4 or 2x6, but the concrete foundation wall would be a minimum of 6" thick. It would seem that if the sills overhang by 2-2.5" then that overhanging edge would have to be supported by vertical (pressure treated?) 2x2s or 2x3s to carry the load of the wall to the floor.

Comment: The framed walls are  probably flush with the outside edge of the sill plate, and securely over the foundation walls. My guess is that someone ordered too-large sill plate material. They're usually 2x8 or 2x10, depending on foundation wall thickness.

Comment: Would studs be bearing on the top of these sills and if so do the studs go all the way to the inside edge?